# What is in energy drinks?

Tags: nutrition, energy-drinks

What (in layman's terms) is in the following drinks:

- Red Bull
- Monster
- Rock Star
- 5 Hour Energy
- Mountain Dew Kickstarter

Is there any coffee or tea in the above drinks. (I don't drink coffee or tea)

Answer (score 1):

It's nicely summarized in "[Energy Drink Breakdown: What’s in a Red Bull, Anyway?](http://www.organicauthority.com/health/energy-drink-breakdown-whats-in-a-red-bull-anyway.html)":

> Basically, Red Bull is a mix of sugar, caffeine, taurine and several B vitamins, all of which are well known for their energy-promoting qualities.

As far as I know, it's true for all energy drinks. So yes, they contain caffeine which is also the main ingredient of coffee and tea (as theine). I have never seen energy drink without caffeine.

Comment: What is taurine? I am fine with consuming caffeine, but I don't consume coffee or tea.